Javascript dual slider: don't let the right slider push the left one
I have a simple dual slider as seen below.
The left slider can not push the right slider any more to the right as intended, but the right slider pushes the left slider to the left and I don't know how to prevent this.
What am I missing?


      // Elements for the sliders and display
      const minSlider = document.getElementById("minL");
      const maxSlider = document.getElementById("maxL");
      const rangeDisplay = document.getElementById("rangeDisplay");

      // Update the display and enforce slider constraints
      function updateSliders() {
        let minL = parseInt(minSlider.value);
        let maxL = parseInt(maxSlider.value);

        // Prevent the minSlider from exceeding maxSlider's value
        if (minL > maxL) {
          minSlider.value = maxL;
          minL = maxL;
        }

        // Update the displayed range
        rangeDisplay.textContent = `${minL} - ${maxL}`;
      }

      // Attach input event listeners for live updating
      minSlider.addEventListener("input", updateSliders);
      maxSlider.addEventListener("input", updateSliders);

      // Initial display update
      updateSliders();
  .slider-container {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 400px;
      height: 20px;
  }

  #minL, #maxL {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      pointer-events: none;
  }

  #minL::-webkit-slider-thumb, #maxL::-webkit-slider-thumb {
      pointer-events: auto;
      height: 18px;
      width: 18px;
      background-color: #333;
      cursor: pointer;
  }
    <div id="controls">
      <label>Range: <span id="rangeDisplay">0 - 70</span></label>
      <div class="slider-container">
        <input type="range" id="minL" min="0" max="360" value="0" step="1">
        <input type="range" id="maxL" min="0" max="360" value="70" step="1">
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>




// Prevent the minSlider from exceeding maxSlider's value - that part has explicitly been implemented in your script; but nothing for the equivalent in the "other direction."

I tried that, it does nothing https://playcode.io/2138558

You can not just apply the "opposite" condition for the other direction here - you need to first of all take into account, which of the sliders you are currently dragging.
One simple way to do that in this instance, would be to check the ID of the event target, whether that is minL or maxL.
function updateSliders(e) - I added the e parameter here, so that your function takes the event object instance as parameter.
And since you are also calling updateSliders(); for the initial display, where no Event instance will get passed, I a also checking whether e even exists, before trying to access its target.


// Elements for the sliders and display
      const minSlider = document.getElementById("minL");
      const maxSlider = document.getElementById("maxL");
      const rangeDisplay = document.getElementById("rangeDisplay");

      // Update the display and enforce slider constraints
      function updateSliders(e) {
        let minL = parseInt(minSlider.value);
        let maxL = parseInt(maxSlider.value);

        // Prevent the minSlider from exceeding maxSlider's value
        if (e && e.target.id == "minL" && minL > maxL) {
          minSlider.value = maxL;
          minL = maxL;
        }
        // Prevent the maxSlider from going below minSlider's value
        if (e && e.target.id == "maxL" && maxL < minL) {
          maxSlider.value = minL;
          maxL = minL;
        }

        // Update the displayed range
        rangeDisplay.textContent = `${minL} - ${maxL}`;
      }

      // Attach input event listeners for live updating
      minSlider.addEventListener("input", updateSliders);
      maxSlider.addEventListener("input", updateSliders);

      // Initial display update
      updateSliders();
.slider-container {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 400px;
      height: 20px;
  }

  #minL, #maxL {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      pointer-events: none;
  }

  #minL::-webkit-slider-thumb, #maxL::-webkit-slider-thumb {
      pointer-events: auto;
      height: 18px;
      width: 18px;
      background-color: #333;
      cursor: pointer;
  }
<div id="controls">
      <label>Range: <span id="rangeDisplay">0 - 70</span></label>
      <div class="slider-container">
        <input type="range" id="minL" min="0" max="360" value="0" step="1">
        <input type="range" id="maxL" min="0" max="360" value="70" step="1">
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>




Thank you, the only issue I see here is that if I push the left slider all the way to the right I can not recover it unless I move the right slider to the right first. If I push both to the max right value, the left slider is forever hidden

That's because your min slider thumb is hidden below the max slider thumb then, so you won't be able to interact with it any more. And by not allowing the max slider thumb to go below the current min slider value, you created a catch-22 here. You will either need to implement some additional JS logic, that allows you to recognize and handle this situation; or you might need to introduce a bit of an offset here, so that min slider = max value and max slider = max value, don't actually overlap.

You need to adapt the logic based on which slider you are currently updating
Right now your code just sets the value of minSlider to the value of maxSlider, but this only works if you change minSlider, so you need to do the opposite job when you change maxSlider.
That's why you need to identify which slider is changing and then set the right value for that slider.


// Elements for the sliders and display
      const minSlider = document.getElementById("minL");
      const maxSlider = document.getElementById("maxL");
      const rangeDisplay = document.getElementById("rangeDisplay");

      // Update the display and enforce slider constraints
      function updateSliders(evt) {
        const sliderID = evt.target.id;
        let minL = parseInt(minSlider.value);
        let maxL = parseInt(maxSlider.value);

        // Prevent the minSlider from exceeding maxSlider's value
        if (minL > maxL) {
          if (sliderID === 'minL') {
             minSlider.value = maxL;
             minL = maxL;
          }
          else {
             maxSlider.value = minL;
             maxL = minL;
          }
        }
        
        console.log(sliderID, minL, maxL);


        // Update the displayed range
        rangeDisplay.textContent = `${minL} - ${maxL}`;
      }

      // Attach input event listeners for live updating
      minSlider.addEventListener("input", updateSliders);
      maxSlider.addEventListener("input", updateSliders);

      // Initial display update
      updateSliders();
.slider-container {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 400px;
      height: 20px;
  }

  #minL, #maxL {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      pointer-events: none;
  }

  #minL::-webkit-slider-thumb, #maxL::-webkit-slider-thumb {
      pointer-events: auto;
      height: 18px;
      width: 18px;
      background-color: #333;
      cursor: pointer;
  }
<div id="controls">
      <label>Range: <span id="rangeDisplay">0 - 70</span></label>
      <div class="slider-container">
        <input type="range" id="minL" min="0" max="360" value="0" step="1">
        <input type="range" id="maxL" min="0" max="360" value="70" step="1">
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>




You have the code for min > max
But I don't see any check for the other way around?
To do the opposite you need to be checking for when the max slider is less than the min slider and adjust the max slider to equal the min slider in that case. Try adding this code.
// Prevent the maxSlider from beingl less than the minSlider's value
if (maxL < minL) {
  maxSlider.value = minL;
  maxL = minL;
}

I'm pretty sure your problem is because the minSlider can't be more than the max slider so if the max slider goes under the min slider than the min slider is moving to the left to be less than it.
Edit: I think the order of operations matters too because whichever one goes first is going to get the priority. I'm guessing the real solution is probably to check which slider is being adjusted at the moment and prioritize the other one.

Does not solve the issue, you can test here https://playcode.io/2138558

Maybe it has to be one statement let me edit my answer.

Yeah I think it's because the order of operations if you put the max condition first I'm guessing that one will work but the other one won't work, it probably has to be expressed as one statement somehow.
